# Is HDBSCAN a agglomerative hierarchical clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, dbscan

I am looking at HDBSCAN and wondering whether it is Divisive or Agglomerative? I understand the two approaches, but I cannot seem to grasp which HDBSCAN utilises. Looking for some elaboration.

https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given by the Proposition 1 in the HDBSCAN paper [1](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-37456-2_14). It states that that DBSCAN* (defined as a non-hierarchical clustering algorithm) can by computed via agglomerative clustering in an alternative space and with an additional "Noise" cluster:

> **Proposition 1.** Let $X$ be a set of $n$ objects described in a metric space by $n × n$ pairwise distances. The partition of this data obtained by DBSCAN* w.r.t $m_{pts}$ and $ε$ is identical to the one obtained by ﬁrst running Single-Linkage over the transformed space of mutual reachability distances, then, cutting the resulting dendrogram at level $ε$ of its scale, and treating all resulting singletons with
> $d_{core}(xp) > ε$ as a single class representing “Noise”.